# Different Results obtained while doing multiple runs from same inputs in VASP

Tags: vasp, high-performance-computing

I have been trying to optimize the parallelization parameters in VASP. By varying the parameters(such as KPAR and NCORE) I am trying to reduce the *Elapsed time* that is printed at the end of each line. But during this attempt I have realized the that running VASP with same input multiple times takes different amount of time and produces different results.

Jobs that we were run within an hour have almost similar time consumption but jobs that were ran at different times of the day produced significantly different amount of time. This leads me to thinking perhaps the time depends upon amount of people using the HPC system but as I have reserved my cores using Job scheduler so the compute time should not depend upon usage of other HPC by other people.

Furthermore as the results(converged energy of the system) also varies, perhaps this leads to different amount of time consumption.

| S No. | Converged Energy | Elapsed Time(sec) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -245.41622996 | 945.162 |
| 2 | -245.41628055 | 985.194 |
| 3 | -245.41623049 | 2141.557 |
| 4 | -257.83322281 | 3220.462 |

The above table shows different amount of time consumed along with different energies obtained. If we do get different result and time consumption with each case how does one compare efficiency between two different runs ??

INCAR file

```
SYSTEM   =  Perovskite
# Electronic minimization   

                                                                                          
ISTART  = 0
ICHARG  = 2
# ALGO    = Normal 
IALGO = 48
PREC= Accurate
ENCUT   = 390
NELM    = 100
LREAL   = Auto.
EDIFF   = 1E-6
EDIFFG  =-0.03
LWAVE   =.FALSE.


IVDW    = 11

# Ionic minimization
NSW     = 0
IBRION  = -1
ISIF    = 3
POTIM   = 0.5

# Exchange correlational functional
GGA = PE
ISMEAR   = 0
SIGMA    = 0.026

KPAR = 4
NCORE = 16
```

OUTCAR end

```
 FREE ENERGIE OF THE ION-ELECTRON SYSTEM (eV)
---------------------------------------------------
free  energy   TOTEN  =      -245.41623049 eV
energy  without entropy=     -245.41518985
energy(sigma->0) =     -245.41571017
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POTLOK:  cpu time    0.6164: real time    0.6195
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOOP+:  cpu time 1509.6030: real time 2126.4977
4ORBIT:  cpu time    0.0000: real time    0.0000
total amount of memory used by VASP MPI-rank0   239488. kBytes
=======================================================================                                                                                                                                                                            base      :      30000. kBytes
nonlr-proj:      13629. kBytes
fftplans  :      29230. kBytes
grid      :      60261. kBytes
one-center:        155. kBytes
wavefun   :     106213. kBytes
General timing and accounting informations for this job:
========================================================
Total CPU time used (sec):     1522.199
User time (sec):     1449.966
System time (sec):       72.233
Elapsed time (sec):     2141.557
Maximum memory used (kb):      317960.
Average memory used (kb):           0.
Minor page faults:       552929
Major page faults:        13110
Voluntary context switches:        18856
```

Script used for running the jobs

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -N dp
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=8
#PBS -l walltime=240:00:00
#PBS -o out.txt
#PBS -e err.txt
#PBS -joe
#PBS -q externalq
# ## export environment variable from current session to job run-time ... better to use this always.
#PBS -V
# ulimit -l unlimited
module load intel/2018.3.222 gcc/6.1.0
module load vasp/5.4.4
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
NPROCS=`wc -l < $PBS_NODEFILE`
echo $NPROCS
#export AMBERHOME=/scf-data/software/AMBER/amber18_intel/
#PATH=/scf-data/software/AMBER/amber18_intel/bin:$PATH
#source /scf-data/software/AMBER/amber18_intel/amber.sh
#export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
#export I_MPI_PRINT_VERSION=1
mpirun -np 32  /scf-data/apps/vasp/vasp-5.4.4/vasp
exit
```

Comment: To keep things from getting too long here, comments have been moved to the [VASP chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62034311#62034311).

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out?